# Select a value and convert to random string

Tags: php, mysql, random

I want to select a value from my database table.

However, after select that value, I need to convert it to a random string which its length is only 9 character.

For example

```
  SELECT dataValue FROM myTable ORDER BY id
```

The real dataValue

```
   +------+
   |  234 |
   |  325 |
   |  335 |
   |  3e5 |
   |  335 |
   |  3w5 |
   +------+
```

Now when I loop the dataValue from the database,

```
   +-------------------+
   |  asdasdsavdcvx234 |
   |  3fdgdfsdfsdfsg25 |
   |  3asdaghfjktrse35 |
   |  3ehgfhewrsdfsdf5 |
   |  3342ret5432qwq35 |
   |  343ty54ewrw23rw5 |
   +-------------------+
```

All of them is unique.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Comment: What would this value be used for? Is there any need to convert from "random" value back to the original value?

Comment: @deceze, no this is just for javscript purpose, because I need a unique id with particular length.

Comment: Then something like `substr(sha1($value), 0, 9)` is *probably* good enough, but you need to be aware of probabilities in this case, since it's not 100% guaranteed to produce entirely unique values. Depending on what exactly this is used for it may be better to come up with your own scheme, but for that we'd need more information.

Comment: It looks like your mangled IDs also include digits from original ids. Is this a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(dataValue), 0, 9) AS otherdataValue FROM myTable ORDER BY id;
```

Use
MYSQL

[SUBSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) and [MD5()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5)

Comment: Function SUBSTRING doesn't exist. Check the function name parsing and resolution section in the reference manual..

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:** try using:

```
 select substr(md5(dataValue),1,10) as inst from myTable ORDER BY id;
```

**NOTE:** in mysql you should give `index from 1 not from 0`.using 0 won't return anything.
see here for more info:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Comment: How to limit the length?

Comment: @alisa use substring like this: SUBSTRING(md5(dataValue), 0, 15)

Comment: Function SUBSTRING doesn't exist. Check the function name parsing and resolution section in the reference manual.

Comment: @alisa try edited sql, sorry i was also not knowing index 0 does not work in mysql just came to know.

Answer (score 0):

you can use inbuilt mysql function `md5()` `encode()` and more

```
SELECT MD5(dataValue) FROM myTable ORDER BY id;
```

for more functions :- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Comment: How to limit the length?

Comment: choose encode() then